# How to close windows from alt+tab view

Tags: gnome

Is there a way to close open windows directly from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> view? Or is there any talk of this feature being included possibly in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first press back quote while holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> to emphasise the window in the selector and then press <kbd>F4</kbd> again while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to close the selected window.

You can not close a window while switching with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> because it shows a group of windows, not just one window.

Comment: This is what I have been doing. Do you know if there are any plans to include a feature to close a window in ALT+TAB in the future, like in OSX

Answer (score 5):

Some things have changed on GNOME since 2012, so [Scarlet's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/104989/618353) does not work exactly as described anymore.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> now shows *windows previews* from the current workspace, while <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shows *grouped applications previews* from all workspaces. Individual windows of an application can be accessed from <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> by pressing <kbd>`</kbd> (the key above <kbd>Tab</kbd>) while holding down <kbd>Super</kbd>. Also [see this Unix & Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/465681/whats-the-difference-between-supertab-and-alttab-on-gnome) for the difference between <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

On recent Ubuntu versions, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and then <kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>W</kbd> while holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> on the selected window to close it.

You can also do the same from the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> view, but you must first enter the windows subgroup with <kbd>`</kbd> and select the window you wish to close. Then press <kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>W</kbd> while holding down <kbd>Super</kbd> on the selected window to close it.